# Creating WebControls from fully qualified path (assembly name?)

Tags: asp.net, reflection, fully-qualified-naming

I have a webpage in ASP.NET 3.5 that will be creating WebControls dynamically. The WebControls that it will be creating will be known by their fully qualified path (ie - System.Web.UI.WebControls.whatever). The reason for this is because I am allowing the user to decide what controls will go on the webpage. Of course, there's more complexity than this, but that is it in a nutshell.

**Simply put - how do I create a WebControl on a webpage by it's fully qualified path?**

I realize that the answer will probably end up using reflection, but I have little experience using reflection and I don't want to shoot myself in the foot by making a newbie mistake.

Comment: Are all possible types known at compile time? This would give you some more options. Reflection is definitely possible, but it may end up being a hassle if you have to set a lot of individual properties on each webcontrol.

Comment: You make a good point, and one that I knew I would have to tackle at some point if I went this direction. Truth be told, I'm still not convinced that I will pursue this path, because, as you said, there are numerous properties that I will be accessing on the webcontrols and I wasn't sure how much complexity would be added in attempting to access them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to call this way: `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("TypeName"));`

where TypeName is **fully qualified name**, including assembly. in my case it looked this way:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"));
```

to be sure about full name in your case, try to output `typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label).FullName` and use it as a pattern

Comment: The only thing to remember is that the `Activator` only works with public classes that implements a default constructor, that is, a parameterless constructor.

Comment: i disagree. It can instantiate private classes if you manage to dig out Type object from Assembly object. about parameterless contructor also not true, you can pass parameters to constructor as second parameter to CreateInstance

Answer (score 1):

```
object widget = Activator.CreateInstance ( Assembly.GetType ( name ) );
```

where name is the string of the fully qualified type

Comment: The only thing to remember is that the `Activator` only works with public classes that implements a default constructor, that is, a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I think this is close, but not quite there yet. Assembly has no static method of GetType(), but an instance of Assembly does, of course.

Comment: you can also do typeof( x ) to get the type needed for Activator.CreateInstance. x then equals System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Textbox, or any other type you want to dynamically create